# mysql - Access tool for support team

Tags: mysql

I have mysql server running on amazon ec2 instance (running on ubuntu)

My support team (running on windows) needs access to this database so they can run some queries and get info straight from the database. Are there any tools in windows that offer such functionality

Comment: Do you just want human access to view/query the database or is this some windows client app that needs programmatic access?

Comment: I need for human access who can view/query from the database

Answer (score 0):

For querying, I personally use [Toad for MySQL](http://www.quest.com/toad-for-mysql/) as it allows me to easily export to Excel. Unfortunately, it's .Net, so it has some very annoying bugs. My co-workers have spoken highly of [Sql Yog](http://www.webyog.com/en/) and [MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/).

For data modeling, I really like [MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/). If money isn't an object, you might look at [ErWin](http://erwin.com/).

Answer (score 0):

1. [MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) support remote conectivity to any MySQL Server, but you need to perform your server security with remote access in server side and DB side.
2. Some servers use [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php) as client (IE Windows compatible). You don't need remote access if you install it on your server but have to check security permissons to your DB side also.

Comment: I have phpmyadmin installed on my server. I think it is little complex for the support team to understand. I will look into MYSQL workbench.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using Navicat if you are willing to pay for the licenses.  It would be the most user friendly solution IMO.  You can download free trials.

Answer (score 0):

Take advantage of [dbForge Studio for MySQL](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/). There is free express edition.